# Postfix not forwarding, just storing emails in user accounts

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta

I have in the past followed [this guide](http://willjackson.org/blog/configure-postfix-forward-e-mail-external-address) and successfully forwarded incoming emails. However only recently this has stopped and all the emails are being stored in the respective user accounts.

The server is not blacklisted and no errors are being reported.

Is there anything i can try?

The virtual file is not reporting any errors.

This is the `main.cf` file:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

This is an example of my `virtual` file:

```
nsw@example.com nsw
nsw personal@email.com
```

Comment: There are always somethings you can try. How about trying to post your relevant config and logs for starters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it worked before and the mail stays in the mailbox than there is simply no forwarding done. 
Assuming you have tried:

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Have you tried checking if your forwarding adress is still correct in:

```
sudo vi /etc/postfix/virtual
```

If this checks out te be ok you could also redo:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

If this still does not work than you could post your /etc/postfix/main.cf (minus personal information) and the /var/log/mail.info log of your last email attempt.

These last two files show very valuable information for solving problems in postfix.

Comment: Hi Embed, thanks so much for helping out. I have checked the log file and all that is occurring is the emails are being delivered to the mailboxes of the email accounts, but the emails are not being forwarded.

Comment: Hi Alex, is your local ip also in the 'mynetworks =' range from /etc/postfix/main.cf ? For example my homeserver his local ip is 192.168.1.10 so i have the settings:
**'mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/50'**.

I also see that you are missing: **'virtual_alias_domains = domain1.com, domain2.com'
    'virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual'** in your main.cf file. can your confim this?

Comment: without the **virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual** line in main.cf the virtual file wil not be used. Best to check this one first. After making changes dont forget to use **sudo newaliases** and **sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload && sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart** to make these changes work.

Comment: Thanks so much Embed, i was missing this `virtual_alias_maps` in the main.cf file.